# QFT for an extended electron

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, volume

Has somebody already formulated a QFT (e.g. QED) for an extended electron (e.g. as a spherical charge) such that the point particle limit gives the usual QFT?

Is anything know about the connection of UR-divergences and the point-particle assumption of QFT.

Comment: The closest thing is probably string theory. The notion of what a "point particle" means in  quantum field theory is pretty subtle, and roughly means "not a composite object." There's not really a way to have a "spherical electron with finite size" in the classical sense of that phrase in local quantum field theory.

Comment: @Andrew You *could* view the point particle as a Planck-sized curled up 3d sphere in 6 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, L.Landau and others formulated QED for a smeared electron and then tended the smear size to zero. They obtained the so called "Moscow zero" with a "Landau pole" (an old story).

Comment: If the point particle is seen as a 3d geometric structure (3 dimensions curled up to tiny circles in a 6d space) could that formalism be used? (Are there 2 of you?)

Comment: @Felicia: I have no idea about 6Dspace features. I am the same; it is my two computers who are not "synchronized".